# SQL select query returning wrong order by DESC

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my query which is not returning the correct result ordered by `RegistrationDate Desc`:

```
SELECT
    Team,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RegistrationDate, 103) AS RegistrationDate,
    FormFilledAt, CreationBy 
FROM
    Table_Candidate_Info 
WHERE
    Status = 'Completed'  
GROUP BY
    Team, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RegistrationDate, 103), FormFilledAt, CreationBy 
ORDER BY 
    RegistrationDate DESC
```

If I will use this query, it's returning the correct order by `RegistrationDate Desc`

```
select * 
from Table_Candidate_Info 
order by RegistrationDate desc
```

I want above first query should be RegistrationDate order by Desc with group by query

Comment: why you need group by - I've seen that you are using aggregated function

Comment: I want group by query for same type of multiple data should appear only once. @fa06

Comment: just use distinct - don't need group by

Comment: can update that answer in you below answer. @fa06

Comment: it's already there

Comment: your query is not helping me, same output i am getting what old my query output. @fa06

Comment: hum its a question of perimeter i think. You remove date with your "where"

Comment: to help you better, plz post the table structure and some sample data..which you think is not coming correctly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RegistrationDate,103) desc
```

or better if you want really keep order by date (and not text) try this:

```
select Team, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RegistrationDate,103) as RegistrationDate, FormFilledAt,CreationBy  
from (
        Select Team, cast(RegistrationDate as date) as RegistrationDate ,FormFilledAt,CreationBy 
        from Table_Candidate_Info 
        where Status='Completed'  
        group by Team,cast(RegistrationDate as date)  ,FormFilledAt,CreationBy
) tmp 
order by RegistrationDate desc
```

Note: if you want group by date + time remove cast… as date

Comment: 31/12/2018
31/12/2018
31/12/2018
31/12/2018
31/12/2018
31/12/2018
31/10/2018
31/10/2018
31/10/2017
31/07/2018
31/07/2018
31/07/2018
31/05/2018
31/05/2016
31/03/2017
31/01/2019
31/01/2019
31/01/2019
31/01/2019

Comment: your query also not helping me, see above date date giving order by 31/01/2019 should come first, but 31/12/2018 is showing first. @Esperento57

Comment: if you remove the convert ?

Comment: you have try my second query?

Comment: ya i have tried second query, if i will remove  convert from CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RegistrationDate,103) as RegistrationDatethen its working. @Esperento57

Comment: please explain me why its working if i will remove convert to date@Esperento57

Comment: try to change 'as RegistrationDate' to 'as RegistrationDateChar' in the outer query, i think it shadows the Date value...

Comment: Why want you convert your date?

Answer (score 1):

use `distinct` and `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RegistrationDate,103)` in `order by` clause

```
Select distinct Team,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RegistrationDate,103)as RegistrationDate ,FormFilledAt,CreationBy 
from Table_Candidate_Info where Status='Completed'  
order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RegistrationDate,103) desc
```

Note: You don't need group by since you are not using any aggregated function

Comment: distinct or group by in this case its exactly the same thing :)

Comment: and order by varchar different of order by date, dont forget this

Comment: i am not getting correct output, please help order by registrationdate desc should come. @fa06

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan, you can try Esperento57 answer

Answer (score 1):

The reason why results are not ordered by `RegistrationDate` when you convert it to a `varchar` in `Select` clause is because `Order By` clause is **logically processed after evaluation** of `Select` clause. 
Now in first query when you write

```
Select * from Table_Candidate_Info order by RegistrationDate desc
```

[Though writing * in select list is a very bad practice] format of RegistrationDate still remains date in `Select` clause which holds true for further logical processing phase of `Order By` clause. Hence `31.01.2019` comes first and `31.12.2018` later.

But when you convert it to `varchar(10)` to get a required format then actually `Order By` clause is ordering a `Varchar` and not `Date`. Hence `31/12/2018` comes first and `31/01/2019` comes after it.

To resolve the problem if you want to retain the formatting of datetime/date  column in `Select` but `Order By` with `Date` value then simply cast the datetime column back to `Date` in `Order by` clause.

Pseudo code as:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RegistrationDate,103) as RegistrationDate from 
Table_Candidate_Info 
order by cast(RegistrationDate as Date) desc -- cast it back to date
```

Demo Link here: https://rextester.com/WMLQL78387

Comment: using group by how to achieve? SELECT
    Team,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RegistrationDate, 103) AS RegistrationDate,
    FormFilledAt, CreationBy 
FROM
    Table_Candidate_Info 
WHERE
    Status = 'Completed'  
GROUP BY
    Team, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RegistrationDate, 103), FormFilledAt, CreationBy 
ORDER BY 
    RegistrationDate DESC .@Deepshikha

Comment: i got my answer with : 
select Team, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RegistrationDate,103) as RegistrationDateChar, FormFilledAt,CreationBy  
from (
        Select Team, cast(RegistrationDate as date) as RegistrationDate ,FormFilledAt,CreationBy 
        from Table_Candidate_Info 
        where Status='Completed'  
        group by Team,cast(RegistrationDate as date)  ,FormFilledAt,CreationBy
) tmp 
order by RegistrationDate desc .@Deepshikha